# How to configure Spring DataBuffer size on WebFilter

Tags: spring-boot, gzip, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I'm getting a gzipped content from the client and I need to decompress it before it reaches the controller, otherwise I get a jackson parsing exception.

I created a WebFilter that wraps the request and maps the body into a deflated byte array like this:

```
  @Override
    public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
      return request.getBody().map(requestDataBuffer -> {
        try {
          GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(requestDataBuffer.asInputStream());
          StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
          IOUtils.copy(gzipInputStream, writer, UTF_8);
          byte[] targetArray = writer.toString().getBytes();
          return new DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap(targetArray);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
          LOG.error("failed to create gzip input stream. content-encoding is {}", request.getHeaders().getFirst(CONTENT_ENCODING));
          return requestDataBuffer;
        }
      });
    }
```

However, when the request body is too large the data buffer doesn't contain all the data, therefore I get stream exceptions.

Any ideas how to configure the data buffer or how to accept gzipped content?

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way is to rely on the Netty implementation for that, and configure the server to use that support from Netty.

You can create a component (or return a new instance of this directly from a `@Bean` method) that customizes the Reactor Netty server:

```
@Component
public class RequestInflateCustomizer implements NettyServerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public HttpServer apply(HttpServer httpServer) {
        return httpServer.tcpConfiguration(
                tcp -> tcp.doOnConnection(conn -> conn.addHandlerFirst(new HttpContentDecompressor())));
    }

}
```

Comment: something similar you can see here https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/master/src/test/java/reactor/netty/http/server/HttpServerTests.java#L940